# BIRT Report Designer - Change Text of Missing Dynamic Images

Tags: image, report, birt

I built a BIRT report with dynamic images in it. However, when a dynamic image is missing, the following text is displayed in place of the image: "The resource of this report item is not reachable." Is there a way to change that text to something else? I would prefer it say something like "Image not found". Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered how to change the text by using the Visibility attribute in the Properties tab of the Image. I checked Hide Element and added the expression row["Image"] == null. I then created a new label with the text "No Image" and checked Hide Element and added the expression row["Image"] != null. This successfully changed the default text for a missing dynamic image file. It should be noted that I had to add padding to the bottom of the "No Image" text in order for the other data elements to show up in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

No.
But, if your image is on the file system, you might check if the file exists (using Javascript) and hide the image item if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately the image is a BLOB a database. Is there a way to check if it exists in the database before returning it? At the moment I am pulling it into the report by using the Source = row["Image"] on the Reference tab.

Comment: you could use an additional SQL expression to check if the BLOB is NULL and then check this column in the visibility expression: case when image_blob is null then 'Y' else N' end as image_is_null